How to use MapStaticAssets if upgrading from .NET 8
In ASP.NET Core 9 MVC application after upgrading to .NET 9 in startup.cs file, this line
app.UseStaticFiles();

was replaced with:
 app.MapStaticAssets();

according to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-9.0
This causes compile time error CS1929

'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapStaticAssets' and the best extension method overload
'StaticAssetsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapStaticAssets(IEndpointRouteBuilder, string?)' requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder'

How to use MapStaticAssets ?
Update
Target framework and packages are .NET 9.
In startup.cs replacing
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)

with
public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)

removes compile error. However in this case runtime error
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication' has been registered.

occurs.
How to fix this?
.NET 9 MVC application solution template does not contain starup.cs. Application uses ConfigureServices like
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"Keys")
      )
   ....

.NET 9 application template does not contain service configuration.

From .NET 6, the new application template uses the New Hosting Model, it will unify Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single Program.cs file and uses top-level statements to minimize the code required for an app. So we can add services and middleware in the Program.cs file like this:

More detail information, see:
New hosting model
Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0
If you want to convert the application to use Startup.cs and Program.cs file. In the new template application, you can add a Startup.cs file and refer to the following code:
Program.cs file:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Set up logging
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Logging.AddConsole();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();

        // Create a logger factory to pass to Startup
        using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        });
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();

        // Initialize Startup and configure services
        var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration, logger);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the middleware pipeline
        startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);

        app.Run();
    }
}

Startup.cs file:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication2.Data;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;

            // Log a message during startup initialization
            _logger.LogInformation("Startup initialized.");
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Configuring services...");
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            // Add other services here

            //// Add services to the container.
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Configuring middleware...");
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapStaticAssets();
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
                .WithStaticAssets();
            app.MapRazorPages()
               .WithStaticAssets();
        }
    }
}



'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
'MapStaticAssets' and the best extension method overload
'StaticAssetsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapStaticAssets(IEndpointRouteBuilder,
string?)' requires a receiver of type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder'

Can't reproduce the problem. According to the error message, the issue might relate that you didn't add the.NET 9 SDK and Runtime in your computer.
So, you can check and try the following:

Use the latest version Visual Studio and install the .NET 9.0 Runtime (via Visual Studio Installer)


Check the project file, make sure you are using the .net9.0 TargetFramework, and upgrade the related package to 9.0 version.


Open the root folder, delete the bin and obj folder, and then rebuild the application.


Besides, when using MapStaticAssets, refer to the following code:

Finally, if still not working, try to create a new .NET 9 MVC application and check whether it works or not.

Changing Configure app parameter type IApplicationBuilder  to WebApplication removes compile error, but WebApplication service not found exception occurs in runtime. How to fix this? I added updated part to question.
